# await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile() not working for pdf files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using `await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile()` for file picking in xamarin forms but it is not working for pdf files, I am getting the exception below:

```
Exception : 

at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <24e422c426e0468ca1fd74b59870ff08>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001f] in <24e422c426e0468ca1fd74b59870ff08>:0 
  at Android.Content.ContentResolver.Query (Android.Net.Uri uri, System.String[] projection, System.String selection, System.String[] selectionArgs, System.String sortOrder) [0x000a0] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/278/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-28/mcw/Android.Content.ContentResolver.cs:1096 
  at Plugin.FilePicker.IOUtil.GetDataColumn (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, System.String selection, System.String[] selectionArgs) [0x00013] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\IOUtil.android.cs:154 
  at Plugin.FilePicker.IOUtil.GetPath (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri) [0x0017d] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\IOUtil.android.cs:111 
  at Plugin.FilePicker.FilePickerActivity.OnActivityResult (System.Int32 requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00054] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\FilePickerActivity.android.cs:168
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Edited the question, kindly check

Comment: to start with, CrossFilePicker has not been updated in over a year.  You should upgrade to Essentials.  See https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows#the-future-xamarinessentials

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you could use the Xamarin.Essentials. The code below to pick pdf files for your reference.

```
async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
{
try
{
    var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
    if (result != null)
    {
        Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
        if (result.FileName.EndsWith("pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
           //do something you want
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // The user canceled or something went wrong
}

return null;
}
```